# How to pass inputs (not arguments) thorugh command line in C/C++?

Tags: c++, linux, bash, g++

Say I have the following simple C++ program,

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() { //no argv or argc allowed
    cin >> t;
    while(t--) {
        int n;
        cin >> n;
        // do whatever
    }
}
```

and the following command in terminal:

```
g++ -std=c++17 -O2 -lm b.cpp && ./a.out
```

When I run this command, it will ask for my input and I have to copy and paste over the input like the following:

```
7
1 2 
2 4 
2 6
7 5
3 6
4 6
7 2
```

Is there a way for this to happen in one pass? I don't mind copy and pasting each time, however I am planning on making a shell script to automate this for me. Basically, it takes the input stored in a remote HTTP server, and then passes it through a C++ program. The caveat is, for some reason I am not allowed to write files, so I can't do fstream/freopen.

Comment: Just put the data into a file and redirect it to the program. `./a.out < my_data_file`

Comment: *The caveat is, for some reason I am not allowed to write files*

Comment: Side note: `freopen` isn't something you want to do most of the time anyway. I see it all the time in competition code and I've never managed to wrap my head around why they do it. Just open a smurfing file stream normally.

Comment: @kaylum Yes user4581301 is correct I cannot write to files because this isn't my machine, I only have access to the shell script and the rest is unaccessable, so is it possible to execute the command within the shell script itself?

Comment: Best I can do is have `./a.out < echo 'input goes here'` in the script. Unfortunately my bash is too weak to know if that works with multi-line input. Fortunately it doesn't look like you care if it's multiline or not.

Comment: @user4581301 Can I do `./a.out < echo '1\n2\n3\n4\n5'`?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question initially. Please see answer below for one possible solution.

Comment: Unrelated: Please [don't use `#include bits/stdc++.h`](https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/31816095/Why-Should-I-Not-Include-Bits-Stdc-H.).  It will only get you into trouble.  Instead, include just the headers you need.  [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) has a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Process substitution is not the right way to do this. Use a heredoc:

```
g++ -std=c++17 -O2 -lm b.cpp && ./a.out << EOF
7
1 2 
2 4 
2 6
7 5
3 6
4 6
7 2
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use [bash process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) to create a "file" from a command. And then redirect that file to the program.

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash

data="
7
1 2 
2 4 
2 6
7 5
3 6
4 6
7 2
"

./a.out < <(echo ${data})
```

Note that the `data` string is not really multiline in this case but that is not required for the program you have shown.

Comment: `echo ${data}` will discard the newlines.  If the newlines are to be retained, use `echo "${data}"`  The way the user's program is reading input, the newlines are not important, but quoting variables in this situation is advised.